# Как сделать SELECT "блюд" по "ингредиентам"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Есть таблица с "блюдами" и их "ингредиентами":

```
    id  title             ingr
    1   яичница           яйца
    2   яичница           соль
    3   омлет             яйца
    4   омлет             молоко
    5   омлет             соль
    6   капучино          кофе
    7   капучино          молоко
    8   соль с яйцами     яйца
    9   соль с яйцами     соль
```

Как вывести разные блюда с одинаковыми ингредиентами?
Входные данные:  `['яйца', 'соль']`
Выходные данные: `['яичница', 'соль с яйцами']`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/386f1/3

Comment: А кто и почему минусит? Человек оформил вопрос и даже fiddle подготовил, что я редко наблюдаю

Comment: Неправильный подход к архитектуре базы. Если хотите так как написали то нужны несколько таблиц; самый простой вариант - dishes (id, title, ingredients_count), ingredients (id, name, description,...) и recipes (id, dish_id, ingredient_id) + связи проставить и всё легко и быстро считается

Comment: @InDevX, а зачем денормализация в виде `dishes.ingredients_count`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов я бі предпочёл записывать каждый раз кол-во а не считать на лету

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title
FROM recepts
WHERE ingr IN ('яйца', 'соль')
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Вот таким запросом мы получим рецепты, которые содержат яйца и/или соль. А благодаря HAVING мы оставим из них только те, в которых нашлось два подходящих ингредиента, то есть оба.